# Android. cannot open database which is copied to SD card

Tags: android, sqlite

I would be really grateful if you could help me.
My problem is:
My application creates database with 2 tables. I'm trying to back up this database and copy it to sd. This works perfectly fine on emulator, but when it comes to real device the file is copied, but it cannot be opened in any SQLite browser.

The code for copying is here

```
 try {
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

        if (sd.canWrite()) {
            String currentDBPath = getDatabasePath("fieldworker").getAbsolutePath();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), currentDBPath, 2).show();
            String backupDBPath = "fieldworker";
            File currentDB = new File(currentDBPath);
            File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

            if (currentDB.exists()) {
                FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Long.toString(src.size()), 2).show();
                FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                src.close();
                dst.close();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Doesnt exist", 2).show();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

Code for creating table

```
public DBSqlLiteHelper(Context context)
{
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    db.execSQL(TABLE_WORKERS_CREATE);
    db.execSQL(TABLE_PERSONS_CREATE);
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    arg0.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PERSONS);
    arg0.execSQL("DsROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_WORKERS);
    onCreate(arg0);

}

 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Long.toString(src.size())
```

This shows the size of the database which means that the file is actually copied

Thanks
Jim

Comment: what do you exactly mean by "the file is copied, but it cannot be opened in any SQLite browser". How did you open the sqlite file with wich browser on which platform/os?

Comment: i can get file from SD card using DDMS. i tried to open it using SQLite Database Browser v2.0 and it doesnt show anything. Firefox SQLite Manager Plugin says:"SQLiteManager: Error in opening file fieldworkerDev - either the file is encrypted or corrupt
Exception Name: NS_ERROR_FILE_CORRUPTED
Exception Message: Component returned failure code: 0x8052000b (NS_ERROR_FILE_CORRUPTED) [mozIStorageService.openUnsharedDatabase]"

Comment: im using Mac OS X Snow Leopard

Comment: however when I open file from emulator it works and I can see all tables and data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code executes fine on both the emulator and a phone, for me. I bet your problem is with your SQLite browsers. SQLite Database Browser v2.0, for example, is designed for SQLite v2; Android uses SQLite v3 formatting. Try opening your copied database with the SQLite3 command line tool included in the Android SDK.

Comment: No trouble, please check this answer to show everyone you question has been solved.